# human activity recognition dataset problem

Tags: android, machine-learning, deep-learning, weka, sensors

if we have a gyroscope and an accelerometer sensor data and merge them we will have `id, activity, time, accx, accy, accz, id, activity_gur, time, gurx, gury, gurz`. So we will end up with a data frame that contains an activity column and also with an activity-gyroscope column. does it make sense to drop the activity-gyroscope column and work with the remain columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop it if it is duplicated and has the same value as activity. Also, check the time column and see if it is also duplicated. Then you can drop also one of the time columns. Normally, it just does make sense, if your data belongs to the same dataset, publicly available.